# Utilizing Require.js with JQuery plugins - where do I put the code to initalialize the plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

so I have a question about `require.js` and loading jquery plugins. Now from what I can understand, there is a `common.js` file I use to add jQuery plugins and their dependency (`jQuery`) using something called a shim config? Not so sure how that works. Anyways, say I need to load a plugin called `layerslider.js` and in the documentation of this plugin its telling me that the following code:

```
$("#layerslider").layerSlider({
    pauseOnHover: false,
    autoPlayVideos: false,
    skinsPath: '../layerslider/skins/'
});
```

must be put in a script tag before the end of the body tag in order to initialize this plugin. Now that's the traditional way... With require.js I have no clue where to put this code to initialize the plugin and I heard something about having to call a define function in the plugin itself to make it compatible with Require.js? Thanks for the assistance, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your js file that defines a config for `require.js` in `require.config.path` section put something like this:

```
  'layerslider.greensock': '/assets/layerslider/js/greensock',
  'layerslider.transitions': '/assets/layerslider/js/layerslider.transitions',
  'layerslider.kreaturamedia': '/assets/layerslider/js/layerslider.kreaturamedia.jquery'
```

then in a `shim` part define dependencies:

```
  'layerslider.greensock': { deps: ['jquery'] },
  'layerslider.transitions': { deps: ['jquery'] },
  'layerslider.kreaturamedia': { deps: ['jquery'] },
```

And then just start use layerslider as you need in a module that you defined (you will need to include dependency for layerslider).

You must have something like this.

In your html file:

```
<script data-main="/js/app" src="/assets/requirejs/js/require.js"></script>
```

in /js/app.js:

```
(function() {
  require.config({
    baseUrl: '/js',
    paths: {
      jquery: '/assets/jquery/js/jquery',
      'layerslider.greensock': '/assets/layerslider/js/greensock',
      'layerslider.transitions': '/assets/layerslider/js/layerslider.transitions',
      'layerslider.kreaturamedia': '/assets/layerslider/js/layerslider.kreaturamedia.jquery'
    },
    shim: {
      'jquery': {
        exports: 'jQuery'
      },
      'layerslider.greensock': {
        deps: ['jquery']
      },
      'layerslider.transitions': {
        deps: ['jquery']
      },
      'layerslider.kreaturamedia': {
        deps: ['jquery']
      }
    }
  });

  require([
    'require',
    'jquery',
    'layerslider.greensock',
    'layerslider.transitions',
    'layerslider.kreaturamedia'
  ], function(require, $) {
    $("#layerslider").layerSlider({
      pauseOnHover: false,
      autoPlayVideos: false,
      skinsPath: '../layerslider/skins/'
    });
  });
}());
```

Comment: Thank you very much Viktor! I used your method and it works perfectly, I think I'm getting the hang of it now. Its just I'm confused as to when I should use require or define. Other than that, I appreciate your response!